# Why is a FeignClient creating a circular dependency to WebMvcAutoConfiguration?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

I've the following setting

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "my.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
public class MyMvcConfigurer implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    private final MyInterceptor myInterceptor;
    ...
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(myInterceptor);
    }
}
```

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "my.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
public class MyInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    private final MyService myService;

    public MyInterceptor(MyService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
    }
```

```
@Service
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "my.enabled", havingValue = "true")
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
    private final MyClient myClient;
//    private final ObjectProvider<MyClient> myClient; <-- This does work
```

```
@FeignClient
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "my.enabled", havingValue = "true")
public interface MyClient {
...
}
```

This lead to the following error:

```
The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌─────┐
|  myWebMvcConfigurer
↑     ↓
|  myProtectedInterceptor
↑     ↓
|  myServiceImpl
↑     ↓
|  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration
└─────┘
```

It works when I switch to `private final ObjectProvider<MyClient> myClient;` in the service implementation.

Why is this happening? I'm not sure how the service implementation forces a dependency to the custom WebMvcConfigurer. Any why it's only happening when the FeignClient is in the class.

Comment: "Any why it's only happening when the FeignClient is in the class" where is that `FeignClient`?

Comment: @Eugene Missed the annotation. MyClient is a FeignClient.